# React-Native run-android basic Getting Java.Net.UnknownHostException

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner in React Native and i have followed all the steps carefully as suggested in react-native Get-Started. Once the project is initiated and i try to run the same using run-android command, I am getting "java.net.UnknownhostException". To be particular, this issue is happening during gradle(https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip) download.
I am on a corporate network and I have done the proxy setup as well in gradle-home/properties. I have tried downloading the gradle file manually and it works fine in my browser.
Any leads in fixing this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link can solve your problem:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2726

Edit `gradle.properties` in android sub-folder with the following details:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxyHost  
systemProp.http.proxyPort=proxyPort

systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxyHost  
systemProp.https.proxyPort=proxyPort

systemProp.http.proxyUser=YOUR_USERNAME
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=YOUR_PASSWORD

systemProp.https.proxyUser=YOUR_USERNAME
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=YOUR_PASSWORD
```